# Page scrolling error on button click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to scroll page to second section on a button click. I am using following jquery

```
$('.home_scroll_btn a').on('click', function(){
        var scrollPosition = $('#intro-home').offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:scrollPosition
        });
    });
```

The problem is when i click the button the page first scroll to top and then scroll to particular section.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your html to the question.

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly. Just use `javascript:void(0)` as **href**. Check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hwyt7hbt/4/)

Comment: its working now thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If .home_scroll_btn a has href="#" or something like that, it will scroll up to the top. If it does have one, add e.preventDefault() or return false on the function.